# How to create a bivariate distribution from copula and marginals?

Tags: r, distributions

Is there some way to create a bivariate distribution from a fitted copula and 2 marginals? I have finally managed to fit a copula to my stock returns using the package fCopulae and would like to calculate the VaR of a portfolio consisting of these two stocks. As far as i can tell, this can be done by simulating from the bivariate distribution and looking at the desired quantile for the VaR. Sadly i dont know how to create this Bivariate distribution from these inputs in R...incidentally, this can be accomplished using bivd() in S+/EVANESCE package...
anyone know the equivalent for R? Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the function rcopula in the same package do that?  You have to look under the function "Copula" in the documentation.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean for example ; rellipticalCopula(), doesn this just sample from the copula itself? i want to sample from the bivariate distribution that the copula and the marginals create...but then again my understanding of copulae is shaky at best..

Answer (score 2):

There is `rMvdc` in package `copula` for generating random numbers form a multivariate distributions with specific margins and known copula.