# Impose copula on two independent random variables

Tags: r, correlation, copula

I want to impose a Gumbel (or Gaussian) copula on two independent random variables

```r
library(tidyverse); set.seed(1); n <- 1e3
data <- tibble(x = rbeta(n, 1, 2), y = rbeta(n, 1, 3))
plot(data$x, data$y)
```

Here is the uncorrelated plot:
[image]

I would like impose a copula to reorder the deviates such that I get the following:

Gumbel
[image: gumbel]

Gaussian

[image: gaussian]

I have looked through the copula, MASS and VineCopula packages but it is unclear how this can be achieved. Thank you very much!

Comment: Could you please explain what it means to "impose [a] copula"? Would this be some kind of operation data or on mathematical objects (random variables)?  What would the result of this operation be?

Comment: Right now I'm simulating uncorrelated random variables. I would like them to be correlated using a copula distribution.

Comment: We have numerous threads about simulating multivariate data based on a copula: please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=simulate+copula.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/19670 gives a software recommendation but unfortunately provides no description of how it works.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37424 for simulating from a Gaussian copula.

Comment: Thanks @whuber - that makes sense. The way forward is to simulate correlated Gaussian variables using rmvnorm, transform to uniform, then apply that to the inverse cdfs of choice. However it's still a bit of a mystery how a bivariate Gumbel copula distribution is supposed to be generated in R.

Comment: What I would suggest, then, is to edit your post to focus on the Gumbel copula question.  You might consider emphasizing the general question of simulating from *any* copula, but I fear the community might find that too broad.  It's likely different copulas may require different techniques.

Comment: I've figured it out; just wasn't looking properly. `library(copula);
n <- 10e3; alpha <- 3;
gumbel.deviates <- rCopula(10e3, gumbelCopula(alpha)) %>% as_tibble;
plot(gumbel.deviates$V1, gumbel.deviates$V2)`